# PHP Excel Only Generating Column Headers

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I'm a little stumped.  I've adjusted the PHPExcel script (copied below) to pull data from a number of selections the user makes to generate Excel reports.  However, this only seems to be generating the data for the header columns and I can't seem to see why.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
if($members = $con_mysqli->query("SELECT member_id, firstname, surname, username, gdc, group_member, band_title, member_past_price, payg_member, subscription_birthday, member_nextPaymentDate, futurepayid, member_lastTXID, paypal FROM tbl_users LEFT JOIN tbl_bands ON tbl_users.band_link = tbl_bands .band_id ORDER BY tbl_users .surname ASC")) { 
    if($members->num_rows) { 
        while($member_row = $members->fetch_object()) {
            $member_items[] = $member_row;
        }
        $members->free();
    }
}

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Name Here")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Name Here")
                             ->setTitle("Member Amount Report")
                             ->setSubject("Member Amount Report")
                             ->setDescription("Member Amount Report")
                             ->setKeywords("namehere")
                             ->setCategory("Name Here Member Report");

$num = 1;
$xCount = 0;
// end setting page background // 

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'Database ID');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'First Name');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'Last Name');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'User Name');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'GDC');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'Group Member');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'Membership Band');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'Cost');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'PAYG');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'Subscription Birthday');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'Next Payment Date');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'WorldPay Future Pay ID');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'SagePay Future Transaction ID');
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'PayPal');
$xCount = $xCount+1;


$num = $num+1;

foreach($member_items as $result) {
    $num = $num+1; $xCount = 0;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,$result->member_id);
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,$result->firstname);
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,$result->surname);
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,$result->username);
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,$result->gdc);
$xCount = $xCount+1;
if($result->group_member > 0) {
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'Yes');
} else {
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'No');   
}
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,$result->band_title);
$xCount = $xCount+1;
if($result->member_past_price > 0) { 
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,$result->member_past_price);
} else {
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'Unknown');  
}
$xCount = $xCount+1;

if($result->payg_member > 0) {
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'Yes');
} else {
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'No');   
}
$xCount = $xCount+1;

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,$result->subscription_birthday);
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,$result->member_nextPaymentDate);
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,$result->futurepayid);
$xCount = $xCount+1;
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,$result->member_lastTXID);
$xCount = $xCount+1;

if($result->paypal > 0) {
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'Yes');
} else {
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($xCount, $num,'No');   
}
$xCount = $xCount+1;
}

// now finish and produce excel file //
// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Member Amount Report");
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="member-report.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `$member_items` contains something?

Comment: Hi, yes I've ran a print_r on this call, copied and pasted in MySQL and this returns what I would expect.  Just a bit stumped as to why this isn't pulling into Excel.

Comment: `...LEFT JOIN tbl_bands ON tbl_users.band_link = tbl_bands .band_id ORDER BY tbl_users .surname ASC` looks not correct. I mean the spaces between `tbl_bands` and `.band_id` and `tbl_users` and `.surname`. Can you `var_dump($member_items[0]);`?